# what does this Unresolved reference mean?

Tags: python, increment

I am trying to count mouse clicks, by incrementing a variable in python.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial, time
root = Tk()

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.port=0

x = 0
def leftClix(event):
    print("Left")
    if x == 3:
        exit(0)
    else:
        x=x+1
def rightClix(event):
    print("Right")

def middleClix(event):
    print("Middle")

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", leftClix)
frame.bind("<Button-2>", middleClix)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", rightClix)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

in PyCharm, "x" in x+1  is underlined with a note: unresolved reference:

when I click the left mouse button, I get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

What does that mean? I assigned it before... so I don’t understand. I tried making x a global, but that did not help.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: [Why am I getting an `UnboundLocalError` when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: It is assuming that `x` is local. Put `global x` in your function so it knows you mean a global variable.

Comment: When you say "tried making x a global" -- tried *how*? Where, **exactly**, did you put the `global x` statement? It needs to go **inside the function**.

Comment: What @khelwood said - should make it an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood said, mark `x` as global like this:

```
def leftClix(event):
  global x
  ...
  x = x + 1
```

This appears in the [Python Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

Comment: If I assign x in the function, every-time the event occurs, x will be zero.  I want to increment x each time an event occurs.  I am also confused why i cant assign a value to x while declaring it as a global.

Comment: ok, I got it, I assigned a value to x outside the function before declaring it as a global  and that worked.